# Assign visually distinct colors to graphs with undirected edges

Tags: optimization, charts, colors, greedy, graph-coloring

Given a graph G with V nodes and V different colors, I would like to assign colors to these nodes such that the color assigned to a node is as visually distinct as it can get from all of its neighbors. All V colors must be assigned to the
V nodes.

I have tried using a greedy approach in the CIELAB color space to calculate distances between the colors as follows:

1. Traverse the graph in a breadth first manner
2. Process a node. While processing a node, check which neighbors have been assigned a color. The first node gets assigned a random color.
3. Find a color from the existing V colors that is maximally distinct from the neighboring colors.
4. Assign that color to the current node.
5. Iterate through steps 2-4

This algorithm does not yield good results. What I wish to have is all colors being used in the graph such that every node is distinct from its neighbors. Maybe this can be thought of as an optimization problem where we are trying to maximize the difference between two nodes along an edge. Any guidance on this will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any control over the set of colours themselves? If so, the method to generate a set of colours by [Glasbey et al.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/col.20327) could be useful, which also uses colour distance in LAB space but adds a [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) step to reduce the risk of non-optimal solutions

Comment: The provided colors are predefined and can be random. I tried using an approach similar to the manner in which Glasbey generates colors to pick the most distinct color from the provided color at each step of the graph traversal but that did not give good results.